# How to check if a specific form with a specific serial is open, and close that specific form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I have a Form1 which can be opened multiple times, each with different serials. So say:

Form1 - Serial 100 
Form1 - Serial 110 
Form1 - Serial 120

The serial is a public int variable on the Form1. The program should be able open the same form multiple times so long as it's not the same serial. So I need the program to detect when Form1 - Serial 100 is already open, so as not to open the same form twice.

I have this code on Form1

```
public string GetSerial
{
   get
   {
        return databaseviewserial;
   }
}
```

And I have this on the form which launches Form1:

```
Form1 s = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; 
if (s != null && s.GetSerial == record)
{
    s.BringToFront();
    s.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
    Form1 type = new Form1(record, "PendingForm");
    type.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(inhouse_FormClosed);
    type.Show();
}
```

This will successfully check if Form1 with Serial 100 is open, and maximize it if the user attempts to reopen the same form, however as soon as I have two Form1s with different serials open, it no longer works and will open Form1 without checking form serials.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easier, first write a function that finds an open form with the specified serial, like this:

```
static Form1 FindMyForm(string serial)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        var myForm = Application.OpenForms[i] as Form1;
        if (myForm != null && myForm.GetSerial == serial) return myForm;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then your snippet becomes like this:

```
var myForm = FindMyForm(record);
if (myForms != null)
{
    myForm.BringToFront();
    myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
    myForm = new Form1(record, "PendingForm");
    myForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(inhouse_FormClosed);
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are verifying with a single open form, system will not check for second form.

Form1 s = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

Insead of this, take a collection of open forms and execute above code

```
FormCollection fc=Application.OpenForms;
foreach(Form f in fc)
{
 // ur Form1 testing code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Yes I realized that it doesn't check for more than one instance of the form. But using your code above, how would I expose the serial property of Form1? As you understand I am still a C# newcomer.